# Index of an element in ArrayList of arrays

Tags: arrays, arraylist, processing

I have a list of two-element arrays that looks like this:

```java
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

I can get an element from this list using list.get(), but trying get the index of a known element doesn't work:

```
int[] array = list.get(0); //returns an array
int index = list.indexOf(array); //returns -1
```

I am using Processing 3.2.1
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, how you are doing it and on which version of java u r doing it. but it works perfectly fine on java8u51. check it here `https://ideone.com/XEd0rf`

Comment: I'm not using java, I'm using Processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
list.add(new int[]{1, 2});

int[] array = list.get(0);

int index = list.indexOf(array); 
println(index);
```

This will not:

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
list.add(new int[]{1, 2});

int[] array = new int[]{1, 2};

int index = list.indexOf(array); 
println(index);
```

The `indexOf()` function uses the `equals()` function to figure out whether an object equals an element at each index. Unfortunately, arrays don't behave like you might expect, so two **different** arrays that have the **same elements** are **not equal**!

```
int[] arrayOne = {1, 2};
int[] arrayTwo = {1, 2};
println(arrayOne.equals(arrayTwo));
```

This is because arrays use **instance equality**, so arrays are only equal if they are the same exact array! That's why the first code block works, but the second one does not.

One way around this is to create a wrapper object that contains your arrays, and then override the `equals()` function to actually compare the elements in your arrays. But since your arrays only have two indexes, why don't you just create a class that has two variables, and then override the equals function? Or just use a `PVector` instance.